# What is the "flag weight" in my profile?

Tags: support, flag-weight, profile-page, terminology

I have been recently seeing an expression under my profile picture which says:

> flag weight 250

What does it mean? What is it for?

Comment: It means I love your flags @Mehper, so they decided to give you even more so you can keep them coming!

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: Nice to hear that!

Comment: Probably this isn't last time someone wonders about his. Why that text is not a link to the meta answer?

Comment: Propose that on MSO @Olli ;-) Though a tooltip would suffice

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All revealed on Meta Stack Overflow [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight-and-why-is-it-shown-in-my-profile) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117)

> Simply: it is the way we order flagged posts. They still get looked at, but flags by known-good flaggers get seen first.

In this case you're considered a good flagger.

Everyone starts at 100. If you don't see a flag weight on your profile, you're still around the mid-section.

If you flag items and they're consistently deemed by moderators as good or valid, your flag weight increases. Maximum is 500.

The more you flag badly or frivolously, the more your flag weight will drop and the less importance future flags will hold.

You can move your flag weight in either direction by how well or poorly you flag items.

Comment: Maximum is now 750, but the road from 500 to 750 is much more difficult. And you still get the "Deputy" badge at 500.